# Bracktrack In Wi-Fi Not Work

Tags: wifi, backtrack-linux

My Laptop model is HP Notebook 2000 2d28tu i have install Backtrack 5 R3 but Wi-Fi is not work, so which driver i have install or solution to other way to this about.I have many try to solve this problem but not found proper solution,

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning.If you are using backtrack 5 r3 in VMware means the wifi adapter will not be shown to your system as wlan because vmware will not take the wifi.So,i searched in the internet for this problem and found a solution that we can use wifi adapter available in market where it can be bought and connected to your laptop and go to backtrack give ifconfig command to see the adapter in ur backtrack.But I have not installed like this.I have seen the video for this problem.